# Is there a way to change code from this Alapca Github project? If so,what can I do?

Tags: c#, api, github

C# user here! I have been trying to change some code to get hourly OHLC bar information from the main Alpaca Polygon DataClient file on Github.

Currently, the PolygonDataClient file in the repository contains two public Tasks of “ListMinuteAggregatesAsync” and “ListDayAggregatesAsync”.
I noticed a simple change to the path under the ListMinuteAggregatesAsync task where **minute** could instead be **hour**, would conclude my goal! (according to Polygon’s API documentation). Currently the path is...

path = $“v2/aggs/ticker/{symbol}/range/{multiplier}/**minute**/{unixFrom}/{unixTo}”,

Normally, I am able to upload most github projects to my own project, but after my attempts to install this Alpaca project onto my project, I couldn’t get past errors of protection levels or basic parameter labeling. Is there a way to change that one line of code to...

path  = $“v2/aggs/ticker/{symbol}/range/{multiplier}/**hour**/{unixFrom}/{unixTo}”,)

without causing a fuss with parameter errors?

My attempts include:
Downloading the git files to my desktop and loading the project up on Microsoft Visual Studio - recieved errors on protection levels

Github link below for anyone who can help, thank you!
https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-csharp/blob/develop/Alpaca.Markets/PolygonDataClient.cs

Comment: Have you tried opening an editor as Admin?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running it as Admin. No Luck

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT! THANKS

Comment: Might as well post your answer in here.